# Change /data/local Permissions

Tags: android, apk, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I installed an ICS rom onto my Incredible and discovered that I could no longer run applications through Eclipse to test them. I searched StackOverflow and found an answer to why my problem was happening in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639873/cannot-install-apk-on-android-device-through-eclipse), but how do I change the permissions of `/data/local`? I don't want to mess anything up.

This is probably an extremely easy fix, but thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You must be root, open a terminal emulator and on the first line type

su

to give you admin rights and hit enter.
On the second line type

```
chmod 755 /data/local
```

and you will have full Read/Write access.
You can also use the Android SDK, but this way is much easier and quicker.

Comment: I figured that out awhile ago, except I use `chmod 003 /data/local`. Is there a difference?