# Android error message on install "no content provider found"

Tags: android, permissions, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to write a broadcast receiver that gets called for every SMS text message that comes in.   All the published code to do that (that I can find) either has been deprecated or doesn't work.

My code fails at install time, with this message in the log (twice):

```
06-17 10:15:59.316   396   413 W ActivityManager: No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/locator.apk
06-17 10:15:59.316   396   413 W ActivityManager: No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/locator.apk
```

My manifest file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" > 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>  
</application>
```

**Would be glad if anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong.  I'm beginning to suspect that there is no API for reading incoming SMSs.**

My source code looks like this:

```
package com.example;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;


public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private static final String TAG = "locator";

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());

        if (intent.getAction() == SMS_RECEIVED) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                }
                if (messages.length > -1) {
                    Log.i(TAG,
                            "Message recieved: " + messages[0].getMessageBody());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing else in your app? You are not referencing any `ContentProvider` anywhere. Your app is similar to one of mine, that worked the last time I tried it: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/SMS/Monitor

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639873/cannot-install-apk-on-android-device-through-eclipse

Comment: It's not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639873/cannot-install-apk-on-android-device-through-eclipse -- that question relates to directory permissions on a rooted phone.  This is a non-rooted phone, and users don't have the ability to chmod permissions in the /data hierarchy.

Comment: I have downloaded and built the SMS Monitor sample code that you pointed me at, Mark.  To my surprise and consternation, I get exactly the same error message with your code, as with mine:  06-17 12:35:08.108   396   413 W ActivityManager: No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/sms2.apk
06-17 12:35:08.108   396   413 W ActivityManager: No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/sms2.apk  -- I will go try a different phone.

Comment: Did this ever go anywhere...? I'm running into the *exact* same issue now, down to the `BroadcastReceiver` for SMS and everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code (and mine) works just fine on another handset, Mark.  I had flashed ICS onto this phone, and I suspect there's something slightly out of whack.  It's the handset or the build.   Thank you,  Peter

Answer (score 0):

**Look for a(another) error message**

“No content provider found or permission revoke” is a warning that may not mean anything wrong. In the package install case I investigated it's just a warning message that the package URI doesn't contain an 'authority' (userid/password) portion. handleStartCopy(), (in frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java) does:

```
mContext.grantUriPermission(DEFAULT_CONTAINER_PACKAGE, mPackageURI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

some work, then:

```
mContext.revokeUriPermission(mPackageURI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

the message is true, but inconsequential. (removeUriPermission() is in frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/pm/ActivityManagerService.java)

For me, this part of the .apk install process worked -- despite the warning message. Check logcat showed for other messages that might indicate why it failed.