# "No content provider found for permission revoke:file:///data/local on sencha touch app

Tags: android, extjs, android-emulator, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am getting "No content provider found for permission revoke:file:///data/local/tmp/Restaurant.apk".I am using a nexus tablet 7 through the ddms to debug.The app is just made in sencha touch 2.
I am using SDK 2.1.1, with cmd 3.1.2.

I notice this has happened when I have installed a newer version of the SDK and cmd.Do i need to alter my path if i install a newer version?
I notice the SDK folder is not present in the structure after an app is created as well?does this cause this?
Please help.

Comment: This could help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639873/cannot-install-apk-on-android-device-through-eclipse/8646393#8646393

You may want to check the permission setting of your data/local folder path

Answer (score -1):

**Look for another error message**

`No content provider found or permission revoke` is a warning that may not mean anything wrong.  In the package install case I investigated it's just a warning message that the package URI doesn't contain an 'authority' (userid/password) portion. handleStartCopy(), (in *frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java*) does:

```
mContext.grantUriPermission(DEFAULT_CONTAINER_PACKAGE, mPackageURI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

some work, then:

```
mContext.revokeUriPermission(mPackageURI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

the message is true, but inconsequential. (removeUriPermission() is in *frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/pm/ActivityManagerService.java*)

For me, this part of the .apk install process worked -- despite the warning message. Check logcat showed for other messages that might indicate why it failed.